# How to get asp.net controls on instance method called from static method in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, asp.net-ajax

I am using ajax `webmethod` calls to the code behind from same `aspx` page, in order to get data on grid which is located on bootstrap modal dialogue. After digging several hours came to know that ajax calls will work only with static methods. Now I am not getting `gridview` controls on code behind. How to get the web controls in code behind??

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static void DisplayGrid(string iNumber)
{
            try
            {
                InProcess obj = new InProcess();
                obj.LoadData(iNumber);
                obj.BindGrid();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
                GridView gvWire = (GridView)page.FindControl("gvWire");

                gvWire.DataSource = WireDetails;//datatable
                gvWire.DataBind();
            }
}
```

Now the issue what i am facing is gridview `gvWire` is null

Comment: It is not possible to access controls inside the static web method. As a workaround you can use ICallbackEventHandler. Check this article:
https://madskristensen.net/blog/Asynchronous-GridView-in-5-simple-steps

Comment: Thanks i did it based on that..braavoo